# Transformar Proxy Object a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tengo una función que hace `console.log()` de una variable global vue

```
Proxy {0: {…}}[[Handler]]: Object[[Target]]: Array(1)[[IsRevoked]]: false}
```

Yo me estoy deshaciendo de esto, para finalmente obtener un JSON de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
variable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable))
```

Es esto valido/correcto?

Comment: Quieres clonar el objeto?

Comment: No, quiero utilizar su contenido, el contenido del Proxy[0]

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. _JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable)) es un truco para clonar un objeto, pero tú dices que quieres ocupar "el contenido del Proxy[0]", y porque no lo ocupas y ya??? Luego lo valido/correcto es subjetivo, si un código hace lo que tiene que hacer, sin romper nada de otro lado, si es legible y tiene una performance aceptable, para mi es  válido y correcto.

Comment: Es que recuerdo verme forzado a usar el `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable))`, sin eso no era posible acceder al contenido del proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que propones es válida. Como puedes ver en la especificación de `Proxy` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) no existe un método que te permita recuperar el objeto que está dentro del proxy, por lo que es necesario usar otras alternativas.

Aparte de convertir a JSON, aquí te dejo otras dos que podrían ser útiles para otros casos

```
// Alternativa 1: Pasar a JSON
variable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable))

// Alternativa 2: Crear una copia usando el operador spread
variable = { ...variable }

// Alternativa 3: Crear una copia usando Object.assign
variable = Object.assign({}, variable)
```

Algo importante a notar en todas las alternativas es que se esta **creando una copia** del objeto original, por lo que si tienes otros objetos que referencian al anterior y cambias su valor, ellos no verán el efecto.

Como dijeron en los comentarios, recomendaria revisar si es necesario crear esta copia para lo que estás desarrollando o si basta con acceder directo por el Proxy.